# $().countdown is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, countdown

I have got this line in my code

```
$('#timeLeftDiv').countdown({ until: expires, timezone: 0, serverSync: serverTime, onTick: serverTime, tickInterval: 60 });
```

and it is giving me this error

```
TypeError: $("#timeLeftDiv").countdown is not a function
```

The contents of the `timeLeftDiv` are refreshed Ajaxily.  Does this have anything to do with it?

I have included this line in my code

```
<script src="/<path>/jquery.countdown.min.js">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you confirmed in the browser developer tools that the script has loaded correctly?

Comment: Does your `src` attribute actually say `<path>`? Because that should be replaced with the path to your plugin.

Comment: No it doesn't say <path> but contains the actual path.  And the script does seem to have loaded correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

might be the missing `</script>` tag.

assuming you have included jQuery before, try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<path>/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, it does contain the closing tag

Answer (score 2):

Hello I had the same problem, and I fixed it  by using.

```
jQuery('#timeLeftDiv').countdown({ until: expires, timezone: 0, serverSync: serverTime, onTick: serverTime, tickInterval: 60 });
```

As you can see I replaced $ for jQuery, this is because I'm also using prototype on my project, and I think there is some sort of conflict with this plugin.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is unlikely to help. Presumably you're running in jQuery's "no conflict" mode, but why would you use jQuery and Prototype on the same project?

Comment: It's unlikely, but that's what helped me. I'm working on a legacy rails 2.3.x project and prototype is the default js framework, jQuery was added at a later time.

Comment: OK, but yours is specific to a very unusual case, having jQuery and Prototype in the same project. It's unlikely that the OP is in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you include `countdown.js` after `plugin.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my Problem just by removing that

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

because I was having two versions of jQuery loading and also this was in other function. The issue I got was from the countdown. It was solved by removing it and leaving only a function. Try doing it this way: it worked for me.